# no data in google charts line chart

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

```
ajaxPost(action, "getData", params, function(data) {
var response = toObject(data).response;
var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

var array = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < response.occData.length; i++){
        var data = [];

        for(var j = 1; j < 32; j++){
            array.push(response.occData[i].dayList[j]);
        }
        chartData.addColumn("string",array);
    }

    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).
        draw(chartData, {vAxes:[
        {title: 'Title 1', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}}, // Left axis
        {title: 'Title 2', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}} // Right axis
        ],series:[
            {targetAxisIndex:1},
            {targetAxisIndex:0}
        ],curveType: "function",width: 700, height: 240});
            $("#" + "chart_div").fadeIn(2000);
```

});

I'm using the above code to draw a line chart! but the chart is not drawn and states no data. I'm using an ajax response and the data is passed too. no firebug errors and following is the response.! Please help me!

```
{"response": {"status":true , "occData":[{"dayList":{1:9.0,2:6.0,3:4.0,4:4.0,5:3.0,6:3.0,7:3.0,8:3.0,9:3.0,10:7.0,11:7.0,12:6.0,13:4.0,14:4.0,15:4.0,16:4.0,17:3.0,18:3.0,19:4.0,20:6.0,21:7.0,22:6.0,23:7.0,24:6.0,25:5.0,26:8.0,27:9.0,28:7.0,29:8.0,30:8.0,31:5.0},"hotelCode":"BBH","month":"May","monthStartDate":"May-2012","orderSeq":11,"reservationRowType":"REV_OCC_PER","total":5.4,"year":"2012"},{"dayList":{1:52368.0,2:87239.0,3:126683.0,4:126683.0,5:147851.0,6:147851.0,7:147851.0,8:147851.0,9:147851.0,10:72566.0,11:66706.0,12:87915.0,13:110090.0,14:110090.0,15:110090.0,16:110090.0,17:147851.0,18:147851.0,19:126729.0,20:104461.0,21:95655.0,22:104562.0,23:88476.0,24:100402.0,25:111558.0,26:65367.0,27:61136.0,28:75780.0,29:70367.0,30:70367.0,31:111558.0},"hotelCode":"BBH","month":"May","monthStartDate":"May-2012","orderSeq":13,"reservationRowType":"ARR","total":96370.0,"year":"2012"}]}}
```

Comment: are you sure that you want to populate `array` with the dayList and not `data`

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a [DataTable object](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable), you are creating an array.

You need to create a [DataTable object](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) with the following code first:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

After you've created the DataTable, assuming your `array` contains a format able to be parsed by Google Visualization, you need to pass it in using one of the following:

1. A `for` loop with `data.addColumn` and `data.addRow`
2. A `for` loop with `data.setValue`
3. [`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable)

Currently you are doing none of these, so Google has no DataTable to pass to the chart.